# Is Duplex Messaging (Server Push) available in WCF RIA?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, push, ria, duplex

Is Duplex Messaging (Server Push) available in WCF RIA?

As it seems to me, there's no way to specify the appropriate binding (such as PollingDuplexHttpBinding) for the soap endpoint of the domain service to do so.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, server push is not available through RIA Services in V1.

It's the top request here:
http://riaservices.mswish.net